# commanLink don't work in p:dataTable

Tags: datatable, primefaces, commandlink

I have a problem with a h:commandLink placed in a column in p:dataTable. The action method is not called. I'm using primefaces 2.21 and jsf 2.0.
the code like this:

```xml
    <ui:define name="center">
        <h:form id="form1">
            <p:dataTable id="userDataTable"
                 value="#{adminstratorBean.periodicalUsers}" var="user"
                paginator="true" rows="10"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
                <f:facet name="header">  
                        Ajax Pagination   
                    </f:facet>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Id" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.id}"></h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.name}"></h:outputText>

                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Password" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.password}"></h:outputText>

                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Sex" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.sex}"></h:outputText>

                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Email" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.mail}"></h:outputText>

                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Phone" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.phone}"></h:outputText>

                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Birthday" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.birthday}">
                        <f:convertDateTime type="date"></f:convertDateTime>
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Delete" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:commandLink value="#{msgs.delete}"
                        actionListener="#{adminstratorBean.deleteUser(user)}">
                    </h:commandLink>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

---

```java
package wls.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;

import org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable;

import wls.entity.*;
import wls.myEJB.*;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class AdminstratorBean implements Serializable{
    @EJB
    CommonEJBLocal commonEJB;
    @EJB
    AdminstratorEJBLocal adminstratorEJB;

    List<PeriodicalUser> periodicalUsers;

    //Logic Method
    public List<PeriodicalUser> getPeriodicalUsers() {
        periodicalUsers = adminstratorEJB.listPeriodicalUser();
        return periodicalUsers;
    }

    public String deleteUser(PeriodicalUser selectedUser) {
        System.out.println("DEledsfkjsdlkfjldkfjldsk");
        System.out.println(selectedUser.getName());
        adminstratorEJB.deletePeriodicalUser(selectedUser.getId());
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `action` instead of `actionListener`:

```
<h:commandLink value="#{msgs.delete}"
     action="#{adminstratorBean.deleteUser(user)}">
</h:commandLink>
```

The `actionListener` can't be invoked with an argument and is intended to use *before* business logic gets executed (in your action method).

Comment: Is your action method called? Can you debug and set a breakpoint into the method?

Answer (score 0):

you should use
        < p:commandLink> 
instead of 
        < h:commandLink> 
when inside 
        < p:dataTable>.